# Color format switcher is not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

With latest Chrome (43) [cycling through color formats on color swatch click](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles#styles_view) in DevTools' Styles has stopped working. The only way I can switch formats now is to change them manually in options. Is there a way to get back this feature without extensions?

Comment: Looks like you found an issue in their documentation: try **shift+click**

Answer (score 0):

The behavior seems to be changed, now you need to shift+click the color swatch instead of simple click. Thanks @Superfy.